# NET Core Multitenant JWT Validation

Tags: jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a multi-tenant net core 7 webapi, where each customer has its own database and I want each customer to have its own key to generate the jwt token, instead of having one for all.

I've seen some samples but the keys are hardcoded, so this won't work for my scenario, it should, in someway to be dynamic.

I thought of having these keys in a database, but this means that, each request will have to check database and retrieve the key to validate jwt, this doesn't sounds good.

What would be the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeArrays, for multi-tenant, each custom must have its own key, if you do not want to store them in the database, what about store it to the appsetting.json file? And use the IConfiguration to dynamically read the key? What is your scenario for `someway to be dynamic`?

Comment: Hi @Rena, thank you, by dynamic I mean that "n" customer can be added to the app without hardcoding the keys in a file like appsetings.json or in a class.

Comment: use mechanism like keyvault to store keys and you can add keys per customer without hardcoding in your app.

Comment: Not using Azure